# iPhone 4 detection... on simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad

I need to detect if the user is using an iPhone 4, but I need this to work on the simulator (cause Apple forgot my country and there's no sign of iPhone 4 here soon).

I found this
http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-model-via-sysctlbyname/

but running this on the simulator it does not detect the correct version. I mean, Xcode 3.2.3 has two simulators (3G/3GS and 4). I was expecting the detection method to tell me the correct version I am using... but instead it tells me "iphone simulator"...

Is there any way to do that? 
thanks.

Comment: What do you need to detect it for?

Comment: I have some images that need to be scaled down if the iPhone 3G/3GS or iPod Touch 2nd Gen. is being used. In all other cases (iPhone 4 or iPad) the images must remain at the original size. At I don't have the images at run time, I have to detect the device on-the-fly.

Comment: Likely the simulator doesn't actually simulate those parts. You'll have to fake it during development, with an #ifdef or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to detect the system version in your case.

Suppose an image is named `foo.png`, then you just need to add

- `foo~ipad.png` for iPad
- `foo@2x~iphone.png` for iPhone 4

and load the image with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]`. See the [*iPhone Application Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW8) for detail.

Comment: Also, I recommend watching the WWDC 2010 video session 134 - "Optimize your iPhone App for the Retina Display".  All of this is explained in detail there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to check for the feature you require, rather than a specific device. This is certainly what Apple recommends, as it gives you insurance when new devices roll around!

In this case, would it work to check the size of the screen, and use that to determine if you need to scale your image?

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

Comment: this does not work anymore. iPhone 4 will report 480x320 !!! Apple wants us to suffer.

Comment: @Mike - Actually, Apple did it this way so that we don't have to completely rewrite our existing iPhone applications to support the new display.  Instead, they've provided a scale property on UIScreen and elsewhere that indicates how the coordinate space will be scaled to fit the new high-resolution display, as well as the @2x extension for high-resolution images that transparently swaps them in behind the scenes.  This is about as easy as they could make it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Hardware Availability and State**
>
> If a hardware feature (for example,
> a gyroscope) is not available on a
> device, calling a start method related
> to that feature has no effect. You can
> find out whether a hardware feature is
> available or active by checking the
> appropriate property; for example, for
> gyroscope data, you can check the
> value of the gyroAvailable or
> gyroActive properties.

Use

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic, getter=isGyroAvailable) BOOL gyroAvailable
```

of class **CMMotionManager**.

Comment: This tells him if the device has a gyro. Right now the only Apple device with a gyro is the iPhone 4 - but about next year when, for example, iPhone 5 releases with a gyro and a different shaped screen that requires him to process the images differently? It doesn't seem like a very pragmatic solution...

Answer (score 0):

See

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *systemVersion;
//  It equal to @"4.0" on iOS 4.0
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *model;
// Possible examples of model strings are @”iPhone” and @”iPod touch”
```

of class **UIDevice**.

Comment: He doesn't want to detect the software version, but the hardware version.

Answer (score 0):

From Erica Sudan:

```
- (NSString *) platform
{
  size_t size;
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
  char *machine = malloc(size);
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
  /*
  Possible values:
  "iPhone1,1" = iPhone 1G
  "iPhone1,2" = iPhone 3G
  "iPhone2,1" = iPhone 3GS
  "iPhone3,1" = iPhone 4
  "iPod1,1"   = iPod touch 1G
  "iPod2,1"   = iPod touch 2G
  */
  NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine];

  free(machine);
  return platform;
}
```

Or, if you just need to detect if it's a high res screen, you can use:

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
BOOL isHighRes;

if ([screen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    isHighRes = ([screen scale] > 1);
} else {
    isHighRes = NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Mike, you can know if the user is using an iPhone 4 by using preprocessor instructions. For example:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_4_0
   // Do some work for iPhone 4 device
#else
   // Do some work for non iPhone 4 device
#endif
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: The editor removes the # sign, at the start of the ifdef, else and enfid you need to add a #.

Comment: thanks, but this will not detect the device at run time. I need the detection to be on-the-fly, not preprocessed.